# WordPress Author Link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to show the gravatar of a post author, but how do I like it to the author profile of that user?

```
<a title="View posts by ###" href="###"><?php echo get_avatar( $email, $size = '64' ); ?></a>
```

EDIT This is my index.php file

```
 <?PHP

  get_header();

 ?>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('#post-list').masonry({ singleMode: true, itemSelector: 'article', animate: false });
  });
 </script>

 <?php

  function MyLoopCode()
  {
 ?>

 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

  <div class="post-image"></div>

  <div class="post-text">

  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

  <p class="p-cat">In: <?php the_category('|') ?></p>

  <p class="p-author">
   <span class="name"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
   <span class="avatar"><a title="View posts by <?php the_author(); ?>" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($authordata->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $email, $size = '64' ); ?></a>
   </span>
  </p>


  <small class="p-time">
  <strong class="day"><?php the_time('j') ?></strong>
  <strong class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></strong>
  <strong class="year"><?php the_time('Y') ?></strong>
  </small>

  <section class="content">
   <?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
  </section>

  <div class="p-det">
   <p class="p-det-com"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '(1) Comment', '(%) Comments'); ?></p>
   <?php if (function_exists('the_tags')) { ?> <?php the_tags('<p class="p-det-tag">Tags: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?> <?php } ?>
  </div>

  </div>

 </article>

 <?php } ?>



   <div id="maincontent" class="clearfix">

    <div class="leftcontent">

     <section id="post-list" class="post-list">

     <?php //query_posts('orderby=rand'); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=2'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=3'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=4'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <article>

      <p>ADVERTISEMENT</p>

     </article>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=6'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     </section>

    </div>
    <!-- END div.leftcontent -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

   </div>
   <!-- END div#maincontent -->



 <?PHP

  get_footer();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `get_author_posts_url()` template tag to output the URL to the list of posts by a given author (which uses the `author.php` page template). You'll need to pass the author's user ID as the first parameter; <del>I'll assume the user object is `$authordata`</del>:

```
<a title="View posts by <?php the_author(); ?> href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $email, $size = '64' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: How do I pass the users author ID to that link?

Comment: @Cameron: are you currently obtaining `$email` by retrieving a post author from your database?

Comment: I think that looks fine. I can't remember if WordPress already gives you access to `$authordata` though. Could you try to run your theme code and let me know if your link is pointing to the correct page?

Comment: No it just links to the blog root